# sql server functions return true when is the maxdate

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need a function, called TheLast (code, id_order) that, as a customer and an order, It returns TRUE if the order is the last made by the customer.
I have 2 tables 1- customer that have- code (pk), firs_tname, last_name and table order have- Id(pk) , code_customer(fk), NrOrder , Date

My code is:

```
 ALTER function [dbo].[thelast](@code varchar(50), @ID varchar (50))
 returns varchar(255)
 as
 begin

  declare @islast as varchar(50), @data as date 

  select @data=o.Date 
        from order as o 
        inner join customer as c 
        on o.Code_customer=c.Code
        where @ID=o.ID and @code=c.Code

      if (@data=max(@data))
        begin 
            set @islast='True'
        end
      else 
         set @islast= 'False'

  return @islast
 end
 ;
```

When I do the query to select first_name, NrOrder and call the function completed successfully but returns me all 'True'

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would change your return type to a bit, 1 for true, 0 for false but I guess it is up to you. 
The basic logic is: 
1. Get the last Order ID for the customer from the orders table 
2. If the Order ID matches the passed in ID then the passed in ID was the customers latest order therefore set the return value to true. If the IDs do not match then return false.

```
    ALTER function [dbo].[thelast](@code varchar(50), @ID varchar (50))
 returns BIT
 as
 begin

  declare @islast as BIT, @data as date 

  declare @lastOrderId AS VARCHAR(50);
  SET @lastOrderId = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Order WHERE code_customer=@code ORDER BY Date desc) -- This gets the last order for this customer

      if (@lastOrderId=ID)
        begin 
            set @islast=1
        end
      else 
         set @islast= 0

  return @islast
 end
 ;
```